# Inputed tab-key is gone when showing QscrollArea widget

Tags: qt, qscrollarea

I'm making a GUI applications with golang and Qt.

I added a QScrollArea Widget to the application.
But the probrem is occured that <kbd>tab</kbd> can not be inputed for the application only when the QScrollArea Widget is displayed. When the QScrollArea Widget is hidden, it will accept the input of the tab key again.

How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using setFocusProxy().